# insert a row after a group and fill with next row values

Tags: r, list, insert, row, shift

I would like to insert a new row after each group (grp) and fill some of the new columns with the next row values and some with previous row values

I'm trying to use:

```
x<-rbind(setDT(DF), DF[,.SD[.N], grp][, color := shift(color,1L, type = "lag")][, Lat:= shift(Lat,1L, type = "lead")])[order(id)]
```

on a DF:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
b <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
c <- c("a","a","b","b","b","a","a","b","c","c")
d <- c(11,23,67,89,90,100,101,123,200,290)
df <- data.frame(color=a, Lat=b, grp=c, id=d)
```

I'm probably using the shift() incorrect and I cant seem to make it work.

thanks

expected results to be:

```
   color Lat grp  id
1      1  10   a  11
2      2  20   a  23
new row with color from previous row, Lat from next row, grp from previous and if from next
3      3  30   b  67
4      4  40   b  89
5      5  50   b  90
new row as before
6      6  60   a 100
7      7  70   a 101
new row as before
8      8  80   b 123
new row as before
9      9  90   c 200
10    10 100   c 290
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output.  What is the issue in the current code

Comment: amended with the expect results.

Comment: that is perfect! exactly what I wanted.

don't think I understand the code though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We create two `lead` columns i.e. next row values of 'Lat', and 'id' before we do the group by `rleid` of 'grp'.  Here, the `rleid` is checking whether the adjacent elements of 'grp' are the same or not.  If it is different, it assigns a new id to that element

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c("LatN", "idN") := shift(.SD, type = 'lead'), .SDcols = c('Lat', 'id')]
```

Get the `last` observation of the selected columns by the `rleid` of 'grp'

```
tmp <- df[, .(color = color[.N], Lat = LatN[.N], id = idN[.N], grp = grp[.N]), 
       .(grp1 = rleid(grp))][, grp1 := NULL]
```

`rbind` with the original dataset columns, `order` by the 'color' and remove any `NA` rows

```
na.omit(rbind(df[,.(color, Lat, id, grp)], tmp)[order(color)])
#     color Lat  id grp
# 1:     1  10  11   a
# 2:     2  20  23   a
# 3:     2  30  67   a
# 4:     3  30  67   b
# 5:     4  40  89   b
# 6:     5  50  90   b
# 7:     5  60 100   b
# 8:     6  60 100   a
# 9:     7  70 101   a
#10:     7  80 123   a
#11:     8  80 123   b
#12:     8  90 200   b
#13:     9  90 200   c
#14:    10 100 290   c
```